# Use sass not css angular 4 .net core 2 spa templates

Tags: css, .net, twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack

Can you please tell me how i can generate vendor.scss not vendor.css (bootstrap.css copy) like webpack it's doing right now?

I try to use bootstrap.scss and variables.scss & _custom.scss and not bootstrap.css.

Or there are another options for this?

I put

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
```

in webpack.config so i can use scss but i don't know how to use bootstrap.scss and not bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

In the webpack.config.vendor.js in the nonTreeShakableModules change the bootstrap entry to use bootstrap.scss instead of .css

Late reply but hopefully this helps people out having the same problem.